# Не работает проверка наличия отработки в функции

Tags: python

**Проблема:**
Есть функция `check_tags`, если в ней была выполнена работа, то `if check_tags != -1:` не должен отрабатывать, в моем случае он работает. Может я сделал неправильную проверку, как можно решить мою проблему?

**Код:**

```py
            tags_list = ['40ТЕСТ8381', '41ТЕСТ8381', '42ТЕСТ8381', '43ТЕСТ8381', '44ТЕСТ8381', '45ТЕСТ8381',
                         '46ТЕСТ8381', '47ТЕСТ8381']

            if msg.find('ВНИМАНИЕ') != -1:
                def check_tags():
                    for tags in tags_list:
                        if msg.find(tags) != -1:
                            conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
                            cur = conn.cursor()
                            cur.execute('SELECT group_id FROM groups WHERE study_group=?', (tags,))
                            group_check = cur.fetchall()
                            if len(group_check) == 0:
                                print('Беседа группы не подключена!')
                            else:
                                for group_advert in group_check:
                                    bot.send_message(group_advert[0], text=msg)
                            cur.close()
                            conn.close()
                check_tags()
                if check_tags != -1:
                    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
                    cur = conn.cursor()
                    cur.execute('SELECT group_id FROM groups')
                    groups_id = cur.fetchall()
                    for group_id in groups_id:
                        print(group_id)
                        bot.send_message(group_id[0], text=msg)
                    cur.close()
                    conn.close()
```

Comment: https://pydocs.ru/funktsii-python-3/

Comment: `check_tags` - это у вас ссылка на функцию, `if check_tags != -1:` будет всегда `True`, потому что ссылка на функцию никогда не будет равна числу `-1`. Вам нужно из функции что-то возвращать и присваивать это в переменную, а потом проверять эту переменную. И вынесите описание функции из кода куда-то наружу, внутри другого кода функции обычно не описывают, это только запутывает.

Comment: @CrazyElf Не очень понимаю как именно сделать выноску и пойдет ли для переменной стандартная прибавка +1?

Comment: Для начала хотя бы определитесь - что и в каких случаях вы будете возвращать из функции `check_tags`. Считайте, что `def check_tags():` в этом коде нет, она где-то ещё расположена. У вас есть только возможность вызвать эту функцию и получить значение: `check_result = check_tags()` а дальше вы проверяете `if check_result ...` Вот вам нужно придумать - что вернуть из функции и как это проверить. Что вы сейчас пытаетесь проверить - совершенно непонятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Нету вообще предположений что можно проверять кроме как числовые значения

Comment: @panickx Ну хорошо. Откуда-то это числовое значение ведь должно взяться. Ваша функция должна его как-то вычислить или просто задать, а затем вернуть. Сейчас ваша функция ничего не вычисляет и ничего не возвращает. А надо чтобы возвращала.

Comment: @CrazyElf Внутри функции добавил переменную `a = 1`, если в функции запускается оператор `else`, то к значению прибавляется `1`, но как мне дальше сделать проверку числового значения из функции в `check_result`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Архитектура работы с функциями должна быть примерно такой:

```py
def check_tags():
    ...
    if некое_условие:
        result = 1
    else:
        result = -1
    return result

check_result = check_tags()
if check_result != -1:
    ...
```

То есть вы должны вернуть из функции какое-то значение, присвоить его в переменную и потом проверить.

Ещё более идиоматический вариант может выглядеть так:

```py
def is_check_passed():
    ...
    if некое_условие:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if is_check_passed():
    ...
```

Если в функции есть цикл и условие в цикле, то идиома может быть немного другая, например:

```py
def is_check_passed():
    for ...:
        ...
        if некое_условие:
            ...
            return False
    return True

if is_check_passed():
    ...
```

В этом случае, если условие ни разу не сработает, то вернётся `True`, иначе вернётся `False`. Можно сделать и наоборот. Можно сделать как угодно, всё на ваше усмотрение.

Comment: Проблема в том, что цикл `for` проходит либо 0 раз, либо 1 и более раз, на это проверку и нужно сделать, разве эти варианты подойдут для работы цикла?

Comment: @panickx Прежде чем писать код, вы должны определиться, что должна делать и что должна возвращать функция при тех или иных условиях. Я же не знаю, что именно делает ваша функция и в каких случаях её работа считается успешной, а в каких нет. Сейчас я добавлю пример ещё.

Comment: Я могу расписать вам что именно делает код пошагово

Comment: Используя последний метод теперь цикл проверяет только один элемент из списка и прекращает работу функции

Comment: @panickx А вам как нужно? Ну, используйте самый первый вариант, проверяйте и выставляйте значения в цикле, а результат возвращайте в конце. Подумайте сами, какое поведение вы хотите от функции. Может вам её вообще нужно в цикле вызывать, или ту логику, которая у вас снаружи, поместить внутрь функции и цикла.

Comment: Попробовал первый метод, все подставил под свой код, сообщения начали присылаться уже 3 раза в каждую беседу. Может я расписать свой код через draw.io поблочно и отправить вам, чтобы вы поняли что должен делать код?

Comment: @panickx Извините, у меня работа есть, мне над своим кодом нужно думать. Я вам наводки все дал, вы сможете разобраться, я в вас верю )

Comment: Благодарю, удачи вам